# Flexigrid for jQuery - How to Edit/Update records in the grid?

Tags: jquery, forms, coldfusion, grid, flexigrid

I'm looking to create a form which will populate with data from my MYSQL database and allow me to edit/update the data in the form and have the updates saved in the database.

Flexigrid looks like a great solution to output results but I'm not seeing how Flexigrid can be used to modify data and save the updates to the database. Is this possible? Is there a better way to make this happen?

Thanks,

Nate

Flexigrid for jQuery - http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid

Answer (score 2):

I recently did a lot of work with a similar product, [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).  It offers all of that functionality and has a ton of documentation.  It uses [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and is themeable with with [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in [<cfgrid>](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_03.html) functionality? It lets you output the data grid in several formats (HTML, flash, xml) and lets you bind the grid to JavaScript methods, a CFC, or normal page requests for handling grid events like the updating of the data within.

Take a look at the "[Dynamically editing grid contents](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=ajaxui_5.html#1137081)" section in the livedocs to read more about how grid editing can be done.

One thing to keep in mind however, is that if you use the HTML format CF will include a ton of external libraries (Extjs and YUI) to handle the grid. You should still be able to use jQuery in conjunction with the grid (ie handling grid activity) if that is your preferred framework.